# File Not Found Error When Running Apache Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, java-home, catalina

I try to run the tomcat using ./startup.sh under bin folder. The console print out following:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java
Using CLASSPATH:       /c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src/bin/bootstrap.jar:/c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:
Tomcat started.
```

However when I go to localhost:8080, it shows the site can't be reached. When I check the log in catalina.out it shows following:

```
/c/Users/zzhang/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.107-src/bin/catalina.sh: line 498: /c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this problem?

Currently my JAVA_HOME pointing to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\"`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on you using shell scripts (files ending with ".sh") and observing Windows paths ("c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11" I'm guessing you're using cygwin?

catalina.sh will prefer your JRE_HOME unless you run with the debug option.  What is your JRE_HOME set to?  If it's set, try clearing it out...

```
$ export JRE_HOME=""
$ startup.sh
```

or

```
$ JRE_HOME="" startup.sh
```